# Identity-H to Unicode mapping problems

Tags: pdf, unicode, character-encoding, adobe

I have a PDF generated by a third party with doPDF program. I am trying to get the text out of it, but when I tried to do it with Adobe Acrobat Pro or any other soft - I received only full of square chars file.

When I extract Font and ToUnicode streams from pdf (with PdfFileAnalyzer), I found, that it could be some problems with ToUnicode table.

I've added screenshot of one of these fonts below(It's A-Z characters set)
And ToUnicode table for it.

Could it be possible to fix this problem with font or with ToUnicode table?

Thanks!

[image]

```
/CIDInit /ProcSet findresource begin
12 dict begin
begincmap
/CIDSystemInfo
<< /Registry (Softland) /Ordering (Identity) /Supplement 0 >> def
/CMapName /Softland def
/CMapType 2 def
1 begincodespacerange
<0000> <FFFF>
endcodespacerange
38 beginbfchar
<0001> <F033>
<0002> <F039>
<0003> <F030>
<0004> <F038>
<0005> <F031>
<0006> <F042>
<0007> <F049>
<0008> <F04F>
<0009> <F043>
<000A> <F041>
<000B> <F044>
<000C> <F020>
<000D> <F04A>
<000E> <F04E>
<000F> <F054>
<0010> <F053>
<0011> <F04B>
<0012> <F04D>
<0013> <F050>
<0014> <F059>
<0015> <F032>
<0016> <F035>
<0017> <F02E>
<0018> <F045>
<0019> <F052>
<001A> <F055>
<001B> <F047>
<001C> <F02F>
<001D> <F037>
<001E> <F02C>
<001F> <F036>
<0020> <F03D>
<0021> <F03A>
<0022> <F034>
<0023> <F028>
<0024> <F02B>
<0025> <F029>
<0026> <F02D>
endbfchar
endcmap
CMapName currentdict /CMap defineresource pop
end
end
```

Comment: Your **ToUnicode** CMap maps into the *Unicode Private Use Zone* E000—F8FF. So it is no wonder you only get *square chars*. The values seem somewhat suspicious, though, as they look like `F000 + ASCII code`. Unfortunately you did not share the actual PDF. Thus, it is hard to tell whether one can "fix this problem with font or with ToUnicode table".

Comment: To expand on @mkl's comment: it looks like the original font may have had its character set defined as "Symbol" and so the PDF generator copied the original encoding into `ToUnicode`. Subtracting `F000h` may return the original characters; or it may not. (On a more positive note: the Font preview image suggests this should work.)